# How to get friendbot to fund my new account using a HTTP request?

Tags: accounts, javascript-sdk, testnet, new-developer

On the [Stellar development guides](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/get-started/create-account.html) it states that using the following code, you can achieve the following:

> To create a test account, send Friendbot the public key you created. It’ll create and fund a new account using that public key as the account ID.

```
var request = require('request');
request.get({
  url: 'https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/friendbot',
  qs: { addr: pair.publicKey() },
  json: true
}, function(error, response, body) {
  if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
    console.error('ERROR!', error || body);
  }
  else {
    console.log('SUCCESS! You have a new account :)\n', body);
  }
});
```

However it states that the SDK does not have tools for creating test accounts, so I would have to make my own HTTP request.

How do I use this code to do this? For the previous code block on that page to create an account I used node.js but now I have to use a HTTP request? Could anyone help me please.

I have tried using `curl "https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/friendbot?addr=<your-public-key>"` in my terminal.

Answer (score 6):

In browser you can use [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) for this purpose:

```
fetch('https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/friendbot?addr=<account-address>')
  .then(res=>res.json())
  .then(res=>console.log(res))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is missing to set Keypair before send to friendbot.

```
var StellarSdk = require('stellar-sdk');

var pair = StellarSdk.Keypair.random();
pair.secret();
console.log('secret => '+pair.secret());
new_addr=pair.publicKey();
console.log('public => '+new_addr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify the OPs concern,

You can use any `Ajax/HTTP` call library from `browser/console/server` to get the account funded

```
https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/friendbot?addr=<account-address>
```

And yes, curl will work on server side